# mixin terminology

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, terminology, mixins

In classic inheritance, `Derived` inherits from `Base`. With mixins, the (technical) base class is usually called the `Mixin`. What is the proper term for the (technical) class that inherits from the Mixin?

I want to know this so I can name my template parameters accordingly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conglomerate_%28geology%29 maybe?

Comment: I think it depends whether you use the fact that the mixin is technically a base class or not. If you cast `this` to a pointer to the template parameter type, I'd call it `Derived`. Otherwise, I'd call it `T` or `MoveConstructible` or whatever concept it has to implement, as with any other template parameter. The fact that it's a mixee seems less important to me than the actual properties that the mixin uses.

Comment: Etymologically, though, it should be "IceCream" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

Comment: Slush has a better ring ... maybe not as etymologically correct though. ;)

Comment: `Sundae` also has a ring to it. After all the derived class incorporates the mixin. There's also the genericized trademark, `Blizzard`, at least in the USA.

Comment: @kenny: "slush" makes it sound like you're writing Java...

Comment: A sundae usually isn't "mixed", the added ingredient is simply plopped on top. The analogy doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a mixin class is an implementation detail that doesn't impact the result as directly as a base/derived relationship in a typical inheritance tree, so I'm not sure it deserves its own name. The one time I used it most successfully there was already an existing base class that was required (MFC's CDialog), so multiple inheritance was used and my mixin wasn't the first one on the list.

If you really have to pick a name, `Derived` is probably as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no accepted name for that.

Try:

```
Final

Concrete

Complete
```